# Notification from Background Geofencing in iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation

Is it currently possible to create an app that "reminds me when I get to work, Siri" right now ? Or the app needs to be running to apply geofencing ?

Comment: Check out: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using the CLLocationManager's [startMonitoringForRegion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3adesiredAccuracy)
which will call your App when entered/left a certain "fenced" geo-area.

**BUT** since the user's location is/will be used, the location icon will appear for as long as this call has yet been canceled (by the matching stopMonitoringForRegion)

(on iOS6 this icon will be replaced with a different location icon for "regional" location instead of regular location use - looks like an outline of the current icon)

Comment: Hi, But why will we be getting a delayed updates, Say i have got the "exit region" alert after moving away 500 meters from my office? in this case how to find the solution to correct it.

Comment: Not sure i understand your question, can you try and ask again?